# Getting ReferenceError: IBMBluemix is not defined when using MobileFirst EnablePushNotification

Tags: mobile, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

I am attempting to enable push notifications with the MobileFirst Platform Foundation service. However, when I initialize Bluemix, I receive the following error messages:

```
"Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError: IBMBluemix is not defined at (compiled_code):10"
ReferenceError: IBMBluemix is not defined
TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
"Uncaught Exception: TypeError: cordova.define is not a function as (compiled_code):1"
```

[image]

Edited to add index.html info

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.testapp.com/blog/js/jquery.order.js"></script>
   <script src="js/Services.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMBluemixHybrid.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMDataHybrid.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMPushHybrid.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMBluemix.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMBluemix.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMBluemixHybrid.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMCloudCode.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMCloudCode.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMCloudCodeService.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMData.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMData.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMDataHybrid.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMPush.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMPush.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMPushHybrid.js"
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please throw some details of your application where you are enabling the push notifications?  I am looking for files  like javascript and index.html if you have one?

Answer (score 1):

@ValerieLampkin, the error may be  thrown if IBMBluemix library  is not loaded yet: check to see you are loading the correct Bluemix.js before the other js libraries. In order to make it to work fine, you have to load all the libraries before your custom code.

```js
<script src="js/Services.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMBluemixHybrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMDataHybrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMPushHybrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluemix/IBMBluemix.js"></script>
```